# SQL Database Design | Roles relationship between managers and group

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I need some help to design correctly a SQL database. Here is what I want :

```
**Group A :**

- Alice (Manager)
- Bob
- Carol

**Group B :**

- Dave (Manager)
- Eve
- Mallory

**Group C :** 

- Oscar (Manager)
- Trudy
- Isaac

**Group Z**

 - Admin (Manager)
 - Alice
 - Dave
 - Oscar
```

A few restrictions :

> 1) Each member can see the planning of the people in their group. For
>   example when Bob logs in, he can consults Alice and Carole planning
>   added to his own.
>
> 2) Manager can update the timetable for the people in their group but not their own! So
>   Alice can manage Bob and Carol, Dave can manage Eve and Mallory, Oscar
>   manages Trudy and Isaac and finally Admin manages Alice, Dave and
>   Oscar planning.
>
> 3) It has been agreed that Alice would help Dave to manage his group,
>   so Alice can manage Eve and Mallory (but not Dave), but Eve and
>   Mallory can't see Alice's planning as she still belongs to group A.
>
> 4) Admin is the only manager that can update his own planning. Also he
>   can consults everyone planning but only people in their group can see
>   his planning (So Alice, Dave and Oscar basically)
>
> 5) User can be in multiple group (look at Alice, Dave and Oscar that
>   are also in group Z). They will have the choice to consult the
>   planning of a specified group when they will log in so it is not an issue.

I would have done something like :

```
TABLE User
id
nom
prenom
login
password
userGroup

TABLE group
id
groupName
groupManager
```

But this will obviously not work unless I could set an Array as a value for groupManager (I'm not good at SQL, but I am pretty sure it's impossible, isn't it?)

Could someone guide me to something that would allow me to reach what I expect ?

Comment: The simplest solution is to create new group entry with different groupManager

Comment: Yeah but how would you get a groupManager to access to more than just its group ?

Comment: For example you could have three rows in group table like this: 1, GroupA, Oscar | 2, Group A, Alice | 3, GroupB, Oscar

Comment: Of course you could swap names for userId, I just used names to make it clear. If you want to find all groups where X person is manager you can just search by that person id/name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your design requires a many-to-many relationship between users and groups (a group contains multiple users; a user can be in multiple groups), I would use something like this:

```
User
(
    ID
    , Name
    , Login
    , Password
    , etc.
)

Group
(
    ID
    , Name
    , etc.
)

Group_Role
(
    ID
    , Role_Description
    , etc.
)
User_Group_Role
(
    ID
    , User_ID          -- foreign key to User.ID
    , Group_ID         -- foreign key to Group.ID
    , Group_Role_ID    -- foreign key to Group_Role.ID
)
```

So your Users table will contain

```
 1 | Alice
 2 | Bob
 3 | Carol
 4 | Dave
 5 | Eve
 6 | Mallory
99 | Admin
```

, your Groups table will contain

```
 1 | Group A
 2 | Group B
99 | Group Z
```

, your Group_Roles table will contain things like

```
 1 | Consult
 2 | Manage                 -- cannot manage self
 3 | Assist
 4 | SuperManage                -- can manage self
```

, and finally, the User_Group_Role table:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 2               -- Alice manages Group A
2 | 2 | 1 | 1               -- Bob consults in Group A
3 | 3 | 1 | 1               -- Carol consults in Group A
4 | 4 | 2 | 2               -- Dave manages Group B
5 | 1 | 2 | 3               -- Carol assists with Group B
6 | 5 | 2 | 1               -- Eve consults in Group A
7 | 6 | 2 | 1               -- Mallory consults in Group A
etc.
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks that will do the job ;-)